# Extract specific type of word from paragraph using natural language processing

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, spacy, data-processing, nlp

I am developing model which extract specific type of words. consider my data-set is as follow:

```
  1. I want to book movie tickets for 2 peoples.
  2. I need to book movie tickets for 2 seats.
  3. I required two seat for movie
```

from above three statement, I want to extract number 2 it may be in integer or string or it refers to seats or people.

I have tried Named entity recognition but i did not get required output.  and for another output I used sentimental analysis. but problem is to extract number of people.

I expect number of people from paragraph and which is may be in integer or string. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')   
doc = nlp("I want to book movie tickets for 2 peoples. I need to book movie tickets
           for 2 seats. I required two seat for movie.")
for i in doc.ents:
if i.label_ == 'CARDINAL':
    print(i.text, i.label_)
```

Output:-

```
2 CARDINAL
2 CARDINAL
two CARDINAL
```

Comment: Thanks @chandan Gupta

Comment: you can mark this answer as correct if you satisfied with my answer

Comment: It gives wrong prediction for following line:```I want to book movie tickets for 2 peoples and having 5 goggles.``` it gives output 2 and 5. So what can I do for only get 2.

Comment: You can apply regex for that.